# Using vb.net variables on html

Tags: html, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to use VB variable names to insert a name into an SQL Server Database from a grid view. It is inserting a row, but the value in the database is the variable name not the value held by the variable.

I have defined names as

```
dim names as string="Mike"
```

and this is how am calling it on the gridview

```
<asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" Defaultvalue = ' <%=names %> ' />
```

and the SQL query is as follows

```
UPDATE [Loans] SET [admin]=@name WHERE [Loanid] = @Loanid">
```

The problem is with inserting the data in the db here
 ' />
It is inserting

Comment: have you missed out some code? "and this is how I'm calling it on the gridview" - then there's nothing there

Comment: Sorry mate, you need to refine your question further so it makes sense or people will start down voting it in a few minutes.

Comment: Iam doing it from a gridview

Comment: The problem is that it is saving <%=names %> in the db

Answer (score 0):

Make your string public :  `Public Names As String = "Mike"`

Call `Page.DataBind()` in your `Page_Load`.

Then access the variable by using `<%# Names %>`

**Edit**

Try setting your string to private : `private _names as String`

Then creating a **public** property.

```
    Public Property Names As String
            Get
                Return _names 
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _names = value
            End Set
   End Property
```

Then set the public proprty to the value you want (Names = "Mike") then you should be able to access the property it from your .aspx page using `<%=Names%>`

Comment: Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event.getting that error

Comment: try it without the Page.DataBind(). Is the variable part of the same class, ie. Is it in MyPage.vb and you are trying to access it in MyPage.aspx?

Comment: Use `<%=Names%>` instead of `<%# Names %>`

Comment: I can access the variable from .aspx the problem is passing it to the db here                                                                       <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" Defaultvalue = ' <%=names %> ' />

Comment: No because you are setting the default value in aspx to "<%=names %>" this is then getting written to the db, which means that the variable is not being accessed properly from your .aspx page

Comment: How come i can even print it bt if i pass it to the db it doesnt take the right value

Comment: I didn't know that, might be worth updating your question to explain that the value in the aspx page is set properly, but not when writing to the DB

Comment: Just seen something - try taking the commas from around where you have `' <%=names %> '` so it reads `<%=names %>`

Comment: If I do that I get this error  Literal content ('<asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" Defaultvalue =') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection'.

Comment: Try using a hidden field instead: `<asp:HiddenField id="fileId" runat="server" value='<%= names %>' />`